# Mousenter cancel mouseleave on cursor re-enter

Tags: jquery

In this example if I quickly move the mouse in, out, in, out the mouseleave event will still fire twice

http://jsfiddle.net/4bsLm/1/

How can I make the fadeOut event STOP firing if the cursor is moved back in?

```
$(document).on("mouseenter","div",function() { $(this).find("span").fadeIn(400);}).on("mouseleave","div",function() {$(this).find("span").delay(700).fadeOut(400);});
```

(note `.on` is required)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to stop any currently playing animation.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bsLm/2/)

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "div", function () {
    $(this).find("span").stop().fadeIn(400);
}).on("mouseleave", "div", function () {
    $(this).find("span").stop().delay(700).fadeOut(400);
});
```